# format time using as.POSIX in R

Tags: r, datetime

I want to put time month-date-year hour-min into my time series data called test. I want to specify the starting time as `2014-01-01 00:00:00`. My code returns error and I tried several times but still cannot fix it.

```
> t<-c("2014-01-01 00:00:00")

> solar_inp<-xts(test, seq(from=as.POSIXct(test,origin=t),
                           length.out=8760,by=as.difftime(1,units='hours')))
```

The error says " 'from' must be of length 1".

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show us what you tried. And read `?as.POSIXct`, which says, "origin: a date-time object, or something which can be coerced by `as.POSIXct(tz="GMT")` to such an object." Your `t` does not meet either of those criteria.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: t is an array that contains 8760 data points

Comment: At the moment `t` is a character vector of length 1, and if you replace the second instance of `test` in the code above as the first argument of `as,POSIXct` with `t` at least the `seq` function will deliver the desired values.

Answer (score 2):

"01-01-2014 00:00:00" is not in one of the standard formats, so (at the very least) you would need to add `..., format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"` to the `as.POSIXct` call. This is untested since you did not include the "test" object.

@Senor O has a good point. It would be better to set `t="2014-01-01 00:00:00"`  ... then things "just work". If your `index` in the test object is similarly flawed you need to fix it, too.

Comment: I think it would need to be in `origin=as.POSIXct(t, format=...)` since `t` itself is what's in the wrong format. `test` may or may not be in the format as well.

Comment: Perhaps: `from=as.POSIXct(test,origin=t)[1], ...)`. You really should have posted `dput(head(test))`